xrandr not changing to propper resolution
I am trying to use an vga monitor with a 1024x720 resolution, however, xrandr is not detecting that resolution, nor dos it show other resolution options for it. Its weird because when doing the live boot install, it detected the proper res just fine. I have already tried adding an new resolution as other tutorials suggested, but it doesn't quite work. i did get an new resolution profile, but it changes absolutely nothing when applied

the live boot install - could be using a different kernel (and video driver) or kernel options. Without knowing your GPU there's nothing to say.
